# Deleting in a binary search tree

Tags: c, algorithm, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I made a binary tree. It inserts elements, deletes them and print the output.There is someting wrong with delete function in the code.It is giving segmentation fault after deleting some elements. Please help me in finding error delete code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct Node
{
    int info;
    struct Node *right;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *parent;
};
typedef struct Node node;

node *createnode(node *temp,int number)
{
    temp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp->info=number;
    temp->right=NULL;
    temp->left=NULL;
    temp->parent=NULL;
return temp;
}

node *insert(node *head,int number)
{
    node *temp;
    temp=createnode(temp,number);
    node *traverse=head;
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        head=temp;
        temp->parent=NULL;
        return head;
    }
    else
    {
        while(traverse!=NULL)
        {
            if(number < traverse->info)
            {
                if(traverse->left==NULL)
                {
                    traverse->left=temp;
                    temp->parent=traverse;
                    break;
                }
                traverse=traverse->left;
            }
            else if(number>traverse->info)
            {
                if(traverse->right==NULL)
                {
                    traverse->right=temp;
                    temp->parent=traverse;
                    break;
                }
                traverse=traverse->right;
            }
            else
                break;
        }
    }
return head;
}

node *find(node *head,int number)
{
    node *traverse=head;
    if(traverse==NULL)
        return NULL;
    else
    {
        while(traverse!=NULL)
        {
            if(number<traverse->info)
            {
                if(traverse->left==NULL)
                {
                    printf("Number not found\n");
                    return NULL;
                }
                traverse=traverse->left;
            }
            else if(number>traverse->info)
            {
                if(traverse->right==NULL)
                {
                    printf("Number not found\n");
                    return NULL;
                }
                traverse=traverse->right;
            }
            else
                break;
        }
    }
return traverse;
}
int find_children(node *temp)
{
    int count=0;
    if(temp->left!=NULL)
        count+=1;
    if(temp->right!=NULL)
        count+=1;
return count;
}
node *delete(node *head,int number)
{
    int children;
    node *temp=head;
    temp=find(temp,number);
    if(temp==NULL)
        return head;
    else
    {
        children=find_children(temp);
        if(children==0)
        {
            if(temp->parent->left==temp)
            {
                temp->parent->left=NULL;
            }
            else if(temp->parent->right==temp)
            {
                temp->parent->right=NULL;
            }
        }
        if(children==1)
        {
            if(temp->parent==NULL)
            {
                if(temp->right!=NULL)
                {
                    temp->right->parent=NULL;
                    head=temp->right;
                }
                else if(temp->left!=NULL)
                {
                    temp->left->parent=NULL;
                    head=temp->left;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(temp->parent->left==temp)
                {
                    if(temp->right!=NULL)
                    {
                        temp->right->parent=temp->parent;
                        temp->parent->left=temp->right;
                    }
                    else if(temp->left!=NULL)
                    {
                        temp->left->parent=temp->parent;
                        temp->parent->left=temp->left;
                    }
                }
                if(temp->parent->right==temp)
                {
                    if(temp->right!=NULL)
                    {
                        temp->right->parent=temp->parent;
                        temp->parent->right=temp->right;
                    }
                    else if(temp->left!=NULL)
                    {
                        temp->left->parent=temp->parent;
                        temp->parent->right=temp->left;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if(children==2)
        {
            node *temp1;
            node *temp2;
            temp1=temp;
            temp2=temp->right;
            while(temp2->left!=NULL)
            {
                temp1=temp2;
                temp2=temp2->left;
            }
            temp->info=temp2->info;
            if(temp1->left==temp2)
            {
                    temp1->left=temp2->left;
            }
            else
            {
                temp1->right=temp2->right;
            }
        }

    }
return head;
}
void printing(node *head)
{
    if(head==NULL)
        return ;
    printing(head->left);
       printf("%d ",head->info);
    printing(head->right);
}

int main()
{
    node *head;
    int number,choice;
    printf("Choose one of the option\n");
    while(1)
    {
        printf("\n1.Enter a element\n2.Delete an element\n3.print tree\n4Reverse the tree\n5.Sort\n6.Exit\n");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                scanf("%d",&number);
                head=insert(head,number);
                break;
            }
            case 2:
            {
                scanf("%d",&number);
                head=delete(head,number);
                break;
            }
            case 3:
            {
                printing(head);
                break;
            }
           /* case 4:
            {
                reverse();
            }
            case 5:
            {
                sort();
                break;
            }*/
            case 6:
            {
                exit(0);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Here we go - what did you find out when you did your own debugging before posting here?

Comment: I entered 5,6,7,4,3,8
then i deleted number in order:- 8,5,3,4,6,7. When i deleted 7 it is giving segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting an element in a BST (Binary Search Tree):

To delete an element in the Binary Search Tree, we first need to look at the children of it and based on that the method to delete a node is decided. Basically there are three odd cases for deleting a node.

The node has no children (in other words it’s a leaf node).
The node has either a left or right child.
The node has two children.

```
public object DeleteNode (object data)
{
     TNode tempDelete = this.GetNode(data);
     if (tempDelete != null)
     {
        if ((tempDelete.Left == null ) &&(tempDelete.Right == null)) //Its a Leaf node
        {
           tempParent = tempDelete.Parent;
           if(tempDelete == tempParent.Left) //Justremove by making it null
               tempParent.Left = null;
           else
               tempParent.Right = null;
        }
        else if ((tempDelete.Left == null ) ||(tempDelete.Right == null)) //It has either Left orRight child
        {
           tempChild = tempDelete.Left == null? tempDelete.Right : tempDelete.Left; //Get the child
           tempParent = tempDelete.Parent; //Getthe parent
           if(tempDelete == tempParent.Left) //Makeparent points to it's child so it will automatically deleted like Linked list
               tempParent.Left = tempChild;
           else
               tempParent.Right = tempChild;
          }
          else if ((tempDelete.Left != null) ||(tempDelete.Right != null)) //It has both Left andRight child
         {
            TNodepredNode = this.GetNode(this.TreePredecessor_Ite(data));  //Findit's predecessor
            if(predNode.Left != null) // Predecessor node canhave no or left child. Do below two steps only if it has left child
            {
                 tempChild = predNode.Left;
                 predNode.Parent.Right = tempChild; //Assignleft child of predecessor to it's Parent's right.
             }
             tempDelete.Data = predNode.Data; //Replace the value of predecessor nodeto the value of to be deleted node
                   //predNode = null; //Remove predecessornode as it's no longer required.
         }

         return data + " Deleted";
     }
     else
          return "Please enter the valid tree element!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your case is when you delete the last node in the tree, which has no children – and no parent:

```
    if (children==0)
    {
        if (temp->parent->left == temp)
        {
            temp->parent->left=NULL;
        }
        else if (temp->parent->right == temp)
        {
            temp->parent->right=NULL;
        }
    }
```

The segmentation violation occurs when you dereference `temp->parent`, which is `NULL`.

By the way, it is not enough to rejiggle the connecting pointers between the nodes. You should also `free` the deleted node.

I think that passing a pointer to the head pointer to te function instead of returning the new head pointer miay be a better design for your function. Not only are you sure that the caller doesn't forget to actually store the new head, you can also save many of the `if (temp->parent->left == temp)` branches, because the pointer to node pointer will already bhe the correct "whence" pointer: the `head` pointer, the parent's `left` pointer or the parent's `right` pointer.